# Java sending xls file but browsers recognising it as xlsx

Tags: java, response, attachment

I'm exporting an xls file from a Java backend but when the client receives it, it is recognised as an xlsx file despite it having the .xls extension in the name. I am using JasperXlsExporterBuilder to build the xls file.

When sending the file, I set the response type:`response.type("application/vnd.ms-excel");`

and the response headers: `response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file.getName());` where file name is filename.xls

But still when the client receives it, the file is called filename.xls but it says `You have chosen to open: filename.xls which is Excel 2007 spreadsheet (5kB) from: blob:` this causes an issue as some excel versions can't handle the mismatch between the recognised type and the file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing you're doing is causing that; the computer that is downloading your file has a broken installation. For example, if the registry 'links' the .xls extension, you'd get that. You cannot detect this and cannot fix it (because you're a webserver; if you could detect or fix such things, you could also do malicious things, hence, you can't, and you never will be able to do such things from web servers).

One last ditch effort you can try which probably won't work (at which point you've exhausted all options available to you server-side) is to ensure that the URL itself ends in .xls. Make sure the user is following a link like `https://www.user3274server.com/foo/bar/filename.xls`.

Comment: I also have the same issue as the end user wherein the .xls file is recognised as Excel 2007 file (.xlsx) but I think LibreOffice Calc handles it fine. So, are you suggesting that the end user should update their Excel?

Comment: I don't know which installer or other tool ended up linking `.xls` to this 2007 format, but presumably _it_ doesn't care about this. I bet whatever trouble you _think_ is caused by this isn't. It's just a matter of a wrong name showing up - which as I said you cannot fix serverside.

Comment: You were right, it wasn't a back end issue, the front end was messing with the file type and name. Thanks for the help!